# Testing variables in PHP

Tags: php, logic

Earlier today I tried to do this:

Example 1:

```
<?php 

  echo $myVar || "rawr";

?>
```

I thought this might print out `$myVar` *if* it was set, and print `"rawr"` if not. 
It printed a `1`, I assume this is the result of the `OR` test.

What I then tried was this:

Example 2:

```
<?php
  if ($myVar)
  {
    echo $myVar;
  }
  else
  {
    echo "rawr";
  }
?>
```

Which is what I was trying to accomplish.

I think I understand why the first prints the results of the `OR` test rather than one of the variables, and also why I tried it - been spending some time on the bash shell recently :)

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to perform the text in example #2 but in similar syntax to example #1?

Comment: PHP is notoriously inelegant here. In most cases this is done with `empty($var) ? "rawr" : $var`. There are [gazillions of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pup+empty+isset) here on SO dealing with this usage of `empty`.

Comment: You mean like echo (($myVar) ? $myVar : "rawr"); ?

Comment: @Jon - stick that in an answer and i'll mark as accepted, thanks

Comment: @Jon "pup empty isset" ey? :P

Comment: @JonStirling: Well, if it's just `$myVar` then you should have already set it to *some* value at the point you first introduce it in the symbol table. If it's an index into an array (like `$_GET`), then you can hide this inside a function.

Comment: @jammypeach: I added an answer that outlines how to best deal with this depending on what kind of variable we 're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is notoriously inelegant in this department, and there really is no good way of making this test.

As a general solution, you 'd need to use the ternary operator as in `empty($var) ? "rawr" : $var`. However, in practice what happens is that you have one of two scenarios:

**1. Your own variable**

In this case where you define the variable yourself, the best solution is to just give it a known default value at the place you define it (possibly with the ternary operator).

**2. Inside an array**

If the array is one that should not be touched like one of the superglobals, then you can wrap the test inside a function (pretty much that's what everyone does).

If the array is one under your jurisdiction but it comes from an external source, you can use the "add the defaults" trick:

```
$incoming = array(...);
$defaults = array("foo" => "bar");

// Inject the defaults into $incoming without overwriting existing values
$incoming += $defaults;
```

At this point you know for a fact that every key inside `$defaults` also exists inside `$incoming`.

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5.3:

```
 echo $myVar ?: 'rawr';
```

Pre 5.3:

```
 echo $myVar ? $myVar : 'rawr';
```

If $myVar may not be set you'd have to use `isset($myVar) and $myVar` as the condition (which then wouldn't work with the shorthand `?:` syntax, as this would echo `1` if it was set, rather than the value).

```
 echo (isset($myVar) and $myVar) ? $myVar : 'rawr';
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5.3+ it is possible to leave out the second argument:

```
echo $myVar ?: 'rawr';
```

This is probably closest to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo $myVar = ($myVar) ? $myVar : 'rawr';
```

or

```
echo $myVar ? $myVar : 'rawr';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use something like var_dump($varname) or isset($varname) ?

Comment: no, i want to test a variable just as I have in example 2, but in syntax similar to example 1. this might not be clear enough, i'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

it's matter of operator precedence. you can't do that.

two points as a food for thought

1. if $myVar is not set, you'll get an error message, not "wawr";
2. by the time you're going to echo some variables, **every one of them** should be defined and have value. That will make your template clean and readable.

Comment: thanks for that. in this case it will always be set, however it may be empty. $myVar comes from a database and while none of my code will run (or echo vars for that matter) if there is no row, some values are allowed to be null.

Comment: all I can say is - initialize ALL your variables before use with appropriate values. it will save you a ton of headaches. all these tricks you've got from other answers are dirty

Comment: again, thanks, but i really don't want to get into a debate about best practice here. rest assured this isn't how I test my database output on the actual pages, and I even sanitise the input too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try
    echo ($myVar != null ? $myVar : "Rawr!");